# How to get full coverage for Java Code Coverage? Junit 5 Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, junit

I am doing an assignment for a course, I need to get full coverage of this method

```
public void ourcompanyname(String companyName) {
        if (companyName == ("")) {
            throw new AirlineException("Warning. The company must have a name !");}
```

---->This is the constructor

```
public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    /**
     * @param companyName the companyName to set
     */
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
```

----->And this is the test I used

```
public void testSet() throws AirlineException { 
        airlinecompany.setCompanyName((""));

Assertions.assertEquals((""),airlinecompany.getCompanyName());
Assertions.assertThrows(AirlineException.class,()->airlinecompany.ourcompanyname(("")));
```

----->The problem is that I get 50% coverage when testing this code. The ("") string represents a blank field, thus when you don't fill in the name, you get an AirlineException. But I also want to test it for a string like "FLYAIR", that should not throw an exception.
What choices do I have ? Better coding for the blank field ("") or just changes to this one ?

Many thanx in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:---

```
    @Test
    public void testUsernameIsNull() {
     
        Throwable exception = Assertions.assertThrows(
                AirlineException.class, () -> {
                    Airlinecompany airlinecompany = new Airlinecompany();
                    airlinecompany.setName("");
                }
        );
     
        Assertions.assertEquals("Warning. The company must have a name !", exception.getMessage());

if(true){

Airlinecompany airlinecompany = new Airlinecompany();
                    airlinecompany.setName("FLYAIR");
        Assertions.assertEquals(("FLYAIR"),airlinecompany.getCompanyName());
}
    }
```

Hope it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Can I input null instead of (''') ?

Comment: No you can't here you r not doing null check. Did above code resolve your issue?

Comment: Now but I eventually modified this code entirely to boolean type for null check.